# BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException in Spring boot test runner and @Rule

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, rule

I am writing an integration test using spring runner, and have created a `TestRule` implementation and used it through `@Rule`. But I try to create a bean of that implementation, I get `BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException`.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'localDynamoDB' is expected to be of type 'com.wickes.dynamo.local.LocalDynamodb' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114'
```

My test class is:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wickes.stock")
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public LocalDynamodb localDynamoDB() {
            return new LocalDynamodb();
        }
    }

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class StockListenerTest {

    @Rule
    @Autowired
    public LocalDynamodb localDynamodb;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

and my config is:

```
My LocalDynamodb is
public class LocalDynamodb extends ExternalResource {
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that you can even inject rules like that... JUnit needs to be in control of those and not Spring. Your issue however is due to proxy creation and you will get a proxy which will implement all the interfaces implemented by `ExternalResource` (and its supers). Either force class proxies or program to interfaces. But as mentioned I highly doubt this will work as control has to be with JUnit and not spring.

Comment: As you can see here at https://blog.jayway.com/2014/12/07/junit-rule-spring-caches/ autowire should work but is not working for me.

Comment: Well if that is out of the way, follow the rest of my suggestions. (Although I would probably tell you to in the end to use a `TestExecutionListener` instead of an auto wired rule.. It doesn't feel right to have part of your JUnit configuration in your applications configuration.

Comment: Actually, as the name suggested it is LocalDynamodb. So I need to pass several components into LocalDynamodb to make this working. And for this purpose, I needed to create it as a service.

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? You are getting a proxy, how you are injecting your dependencies has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

M. Deinum is correct: `LocalDynamodb` is being proxied by interfaces, which you do **not** want.

Thus, you have two options:

1. Convert `LocalDynamodb` to an interface, implement the interface, and register the implementation as the bean.
2. Switch from dynamic interface-based proxies (the default) to class-based proxies. How you perform the *switch* depends on how the proxies are being created, but since we can't see the rest of your Spring configuration we don't know how to advise you there.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Would using `aspectJ` be a potential cause for the interface proxy? We have a minimal smoke test injecting a concrete `@Service` into a `@SpringBootTest` annotated test and get the same error. But we also have an aspect that will advise this Service class, so I'm thinking that's where the proxy is coming from and why we might have an interface.

Comment: Answer: Yes .  Once I added `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` to our Application config, the beans were injected into the test.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to inject an AspectJ proxied object, then I found that you can add the @Scope annotation to LocalDynamodb:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ...
```

More details [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/scoped-proxy.html)